# list groups from user with ldap

Tags: php, ldap

I'm really new to LDAP and just got a connection between my php server and my ad server. I've succefully been able to authenticate users. Now I want to list all groups the users are in to see if he's an admin or not (or there might be another way?).

I have this so far:

```
    $ldap = ldap_connect("192.168.1.108");
    if ($ldap && $bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $name."@foobar.com", $pw)) {
        // ldap_search and ldap_get_entries here i guess, but how?
    }
```

I've tried with ldap_search by reading the manual at php.net but I couldn't get it to work at all. Can somebody show me how to get it to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it working with this post: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ldap.php#99347
Thanks anyway Aaron.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to check out the [ldap_get_entries](http://www.php.net/ldap_get_entries) function.  Below is maybe some code that can help you out that I used to scan memberships. `member` may be something different on your config so I suggest printing the entire `$data` array if you get errors.  Hopefully a starting point for you.

```
// Users
$query = ldap_search($ldap, "cn=Users, dc=test, dc=local", "cn=*");
// Read all results from search
$data = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $query);

// Loop over 
for ($i=0; $i < $data['count']; $i++) {
    print_r($data[$i]['member']);
    echo "\n\n";    
}
```